# terminal.integrated.env.windows for Integrated Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to set variable before start the Integrated Terminal

User Setting:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}
```

Then View > Integrated Terminal

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\bar> echo $foo
PS C:\bar>
```

It's seem not work,
It's bug or I'm wrong?

VSCode Version: 1.16.1

PS: Already seem  [Set global $PATH environment variable in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983718/set-global-path-environment-variable-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, yume-chan answer by question in
Ref: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34420#issuecomment-329705397

It's should be `echo $Env:foo` instead of `echo $foo`