# How do I set an API_KEY in Windows terminal?

Tags: python, windows, flask, visual-studio-code, api-key

I'm having trouble running my flask based web app that uses an api key from IEX. Normally in my Linux based cloud IDE I run:

`export API_KEY=[keyhere]`

in the command line and the program works fine. But I cannot get my program to run locally in my Windows machine. When I run the exact same command in the terminal it says:

**'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

I've found a quirk about the Windows terminal compared to linux from a different necessary command. In Linux I may write:

`FLASK_APP=application.py`

but in Windows I am supposed to write the same as:

`$env:FLASK_APP='application.py'`.

Writing $env: for the API_KEY command results in this error though:

**The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.**

I'm using VSCode if that helps. I tried setting the API_KEY in both the VSCode's integrated terminal and Window's operating system terminal. Does anyone know how to set an API_KEY in Windows?

Comment: That's just an environment variable. You're asking how to set an environment variable. Just use `SET`. `export` is the LINUX keyword. `SET FLASK_APP=application.py`. There's no `$env` in Windows

Comment: Unless you mean how *Powershell* set's environment variables?

Comment: The original question - how to set an environment variable on your machine - isn't programming-related. Hit the `Win` key and type `system variables`. The first result should be `Edit the System Environment Variables` which opens a dialog box allowing you to set system-wide or user-specific environment variables.

Comment: If you ask how to set evn variables in a VS Code terminal specifically, there are duplicate questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595446/is-there-any-way-to-set-environment-variables-in-visual-studio-code) - the answers show how to set executables, arguments and env variables for various task commands

Comment: Setting environment variables before opening a terminal, or executing a script that sets them, is done in VS Code settings, through the `terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows` and `terminal.integrated.env.windows` settings. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635168/vscode-how-to-run-a-command-after-each-terminal-open), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232602/terminal-integrated-env-windows-for-integrated-terminal) and the [integrated terminal docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Windows` the command is `set` as compared to `export` in `Linux/Unix` based systems.

Comment: And even that isn't needed if you add a user or system environment variable through System settings

Comment: Thank you, that worked for the Windows terminal and I able to at least get my web program running. But it does not work for the VSCode integrated terminal which is a large inconvenience. It gives me an error when I run flask run after I set the api_key as

`RuntimeError: API_KEY not set`

Anyone know how to run the web app from VSCode's integrated terminal?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using "Run without Debugging" you can modify your `launch.json` to include an [`"env"` key](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_env) with mapping of environment variables:

```
"env": {"API_KEY": "[keyhere]"}
```