# Error: API_KEY not set in VS Code Desktop

Tags: python

I am experimenting with the IEX API. I have created a website to query stock info via a `symbol` (e.g. NFLX or AAPL) in an IDE provided via the edX Harvard CS50x course and am now trying to set up VS Code desktop to be independent of their provided IDE.

I am struggling to set my API_KEY in VS Code, desktop version.
I downloaded VS Code (desktop version +python, nodejs, flask, etc. etc.), cloned my repository from Github and then tried to run the website to query stock info (which works perfectly fine in the IDE after setting my api-key).

The code for the key looks as follows:

```
# Contact API
try:
    api_key = os.environ.get("API_KEY")
    url = f"https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{urllib.parse.quote_plus(symbol)}/quote?token={api_key}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()

except requests.RequestException:
    return None
```

I get the following error: `API_KEY not set in VS Code Desktop`

I am working on windows and have managed to set the flask app with this syntax: `set FLASK_APP=app.py`

I set the API_KEY accordingly (`set API_KEY=xxx`), but when running flask, I get the error above. I use this command to run flask:`python3 -m flask run`

I tried to set the API_KEY within the app.py file, just to see if it would work (despite security issues), but no success: `os.environ["API_KEY"] = "xxx"`

Any experiences with this in windows? I found this stackoverflow post, but that guy didn't get an answer either: [How do I set an API_KEY in Windows terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59087882/how-do-i-set-an-api-key-in-windows-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work:
My FLASK_APP app.py file was checking if the API_KEY was set like this:

```
# Make sure API key is set

if not os.environ.get("API_KEY"):

        raise RuntimeError("API_KEY not set")
```

I do not know how to set the api key with the correct syntax, so I commented this part out and inserted the api key as a string in my code instead:
`api_key = 'xxx'`

Apparently, this is now a security issue, since I hard-coded my api key, but at least it runs now on windows in the VS code desktop version.
I also tried to hide the key away in a .env file which works ([How to set and get environment variables in python](https://able.bio/rhett/how-to-set-and-get-environment-variables-in-python--274rgt5)) but still no solution for setting it from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me:

```
$env:API_KEY="PUT_YOUR_VALUE_HERE"
```

Note: if you are using VS Code in desktop & not having WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) installed, then you can't use `export` because it's a command built-in command in UNIX/Linux.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you read the specification in full!
https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/9/finance/
The problem specifically states how to set up an API Key. I will paste it here for convenience:

Configuring

Before getting started on this assignment, we’ll need to register for an API key in order to be able to query IEX’s data. To do so, follow these steps:

Visit iexcloud.io/cloud-login#/register/.

Select the “Individual” account type, then enter your name, email address, and a password, and click “Create account”.

Once registered, scroll down to “Get started for free” and click “Select Start plan” to choose the free plan.

Once you’ve confirmed your account via a confirmation email, visit https://iexcloud.io/console/tokens.

Copy the key that appears under the Token column (it should begin with pk_).

In your terminal window, execute:

`$ export API_KEY=value`

where value is that (pasted) value, without any space immediately before or
after the =. You also may wish to paste that value in a text document
somewhere, in case you need it again later.

I don't know if you are still working on this problem, but I'll still post this just in case any future users need help!