# Debugging Environment for Ruby at Vscode

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have been trying to set up the debugger, or something alike, so I can test my code while I start to learn the language `ruby`.

I have read dozens of tutorials, and still now I did not manage to understand how to get this to work.

1. I have downloaded the two gems indicated  + ruby extension for vscode, as per recommended in several tutorials.

```
gem install ruby-debug-ide
gem install debase
```

2. I have created a `vs.code` file with a `{}launch.json` file inside.
3. on the `{} launch.json` file I have typed the following code:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

  {
    "name": "Rails server",
    "type": "Ruby",
    "request": "launch",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rails",
    "args": ["server"]
  }
]
}
```

When I run the debugger I get the following feedback on the DEBUG CONSOLE: `Debugger terminal error: Process failed: spawn rdebug-ide ENOENT`

I am looking for a solution that lets me see the output of functions, variables, etc, like we do on javascript, using `console.log()`. I guess it is the equivalent to `puts()`, or `prints()` on `ruby`.

Please let me know if I have to set something else besides the debugger in order to have specific output of my code, as per stated above.

Really desperate with this at this point. Thanks in advance to all!

Comment: Did you read through the comments here? Make sure you can run it manually from the command line first: https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby/issues/113

Comment: I have checked if my env is correct, but I cannot understand this quite well yet... ```"env": {
  "PATH": "/Users/Dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/Users/Dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global/bin:/Users/Dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Dev/.rvm/bin",
  "GEM_HOME": "/Users/Dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3",
  "GEM_PATH": "/Users/Dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3:/Users/Dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global",
  "RUBY_VERSION": "ruby-2.6.3"```
}

Comment: Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51722136/how-do-you-run-and-debug-ruby-on-rails-from-visual-studio-code/54477794#54477794

Comment: how do I discover the path of ruby-debug-ide so I can set it at launch file?

Comment: @casper how do I check if I can run it from the command line? Thanks for the support

Comment: Type `rdebug-ide some_ruby_test_file.rb` in the console.

Comment: @Casper it did not return the path itself. It returned the following instead: ```Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.7.0, debase 0.2.4.1, file filtering is supported) listens on 127.0.0.1:1234```

Comment: Ok that's good. It means the debugger works. If you want the path to it you can type `which rdebug-ide`. Since it works in the console, something must be wrong with the VSCode setup. Look at the SO question I linked above, it contains some troubleshooting tips.

Comment: @Casper thanks for your reply. I have been trying to figure out how Mitch (his answer) did it on the link you've passed me. But it's all a quite confusing as I am new to all of this =)

Comment: Also look at the answer above by janniks. It has some troubleshooting tips.

Comment: @Casper thanks... on my first comment above is the result of step 02 on janniks reply: ```printf "\n\"env\": {\n  \"PATH\": \"$PATH\",\n  \"GEM_HOME\": \"$GEM_HOME\",\n  \"GEM_PATH\": \"$GEM_PATH\",\n  \"RUBY_VERSION\": \"$RUBY_VERSION\"\n}\n\n"```  After doing that, what do I do next?

Comment: I get kind of lost. Is probably something that I am overlooking as I am new to this