# hello world C++ compiled by Windows MSYS2 g++ segfault likely from missing std lib

Tags: c++, windows, g++

Followed VS Code instructions to install gcc, g++: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

```
g++ -c -Wall -pedantic hw.cpp
g++ hw.o -o hw
./hw
```

Runs and ends with nothing in console.

```
gdb ./hw
run
backtrace
```

Using gdb:

```
[New Thread 2664.0x530]
[New Thread 2664.0xe9c]
[New Thread 2664.0x2d80]

Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fff76446326 in ?? () from C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007fff76446326 in ?? () from C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
#1  0x00007fff764c4759 in ?? () from C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
#2  0x00007fff764d3187 in ?? () from C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
#3  0x00007ff6eb141476 in main () at hw.cpp:4
```

hw.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

To check that gcc works. The following has been compiled & run with gcc and successfully prints.

helloworld.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
```

I suspect the libraries were not installed properly. How do I fix it?

Comment: Probably an installation mismatch: You build with one version of GCC, and at runtime a different version of the C++ standard library `libstdc++` is loaded.

Comment: Yeah, it's really weird that you're using `libstdc++-6.dll` from a separate installation of gnuplot outside of MSYS2.  When you launch MSYS2, it should set up your PATH variable properly so that only libraries and binaries from MSYS2 are used.  You can run `echo $PATH` to see what's on your PATH and try to troubleshoot why gnuplot is on there.

Comment: I believe you can modify your `PATH` environment variable in the VSCode `settings.json` related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662998/how-to-extend-path-in-launch-json-in-visual-studio-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662998/how-to-extend-path-in-launch-json-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: This is [Dll Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell) and not a missing dependency.  The problem is the `C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin\libstdc++-6.dll` is not compatible (most likely too old) with your current / modern MinGW.  You need to alter your PATH to get windows to load the correct dll from msys2 instead of the ones it found in this folder.

Comment: We've been seeing a large uptick in this lately. Wonder what's changed, or if the usual "just throw it in the path" tutorial advice is finally catching up with people.

Answer (score 5):

according to gdb showing `C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin\libstdc++-6.dll` you have gnuplot path listed first in your `PATH` environment variable which causes your `msys2` apps to use the wrong `libstdc++.dll`.

you need to add the path to the following `g++.exe` compiler folder to the **beginning** of your `PATH` environment variable.

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin
```

or if you are using universal CRT.

```
C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin
```

this way apps will load msys2 `libstdc++.dll` first.

Comment: Or not put any of this stuff in the path in the first place.

Comment: @user4581301 but then apps using `gnuplot` will have to use its full path, some apps call gnuplot through the shell and expect it to be on the `PATH`, there is no one-solution-fits-all.

Comment: And then everything works just fine until some other tool's DLL else needs to go first in the path. Shuffling the path just kicks the ball further down the curb.

Comment: @user4581301 apps load the dlls in their folder first before checking the `PATH`, so i'd expect this to run fine on windows, even `gnuplot` should still work after this change. [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order), but maybe this will break if he installed multiple compilers in the future.

Comment: I am being unclear, and I apologize. This isn't strictly about gnuplot. This is also about what happens when ruby is added to the path. People need to curate what goes into the path and put in the minimum.

Comment: The path had what you listed but they were after gnuplot. Moving the 2 paths got it working.