# alter PATH for VS Code Remote SSH

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Using VS Code's new Remote SSH feature, how do I modify the `PATH` environment variable for its terminal? I've ssh'd into an Ubuntu 16.04 VM and it is not picking up `/etc/profile` or `~/.bash_profile`.

[image]

After opening the terminal, I can `. ~/.bash_profile`, but I want something like that to happen automatically.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I modified the path in ~/.bashrc and it worked.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983718/set-global-path-environment-variable-in-vs-code for a similar question and more answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use this command in command line (F1 or ctrl+shift+p): Remote-SSH: Kill VS Code Server on Host, which let the vscode server to restart and reload you config.