# VScode remote not using the same path as vscode locally

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, vscode-remote

I've been working on some Jupyter notebooks in VSCode. Jupyter isn't very git friendly, so when I want to commit my notebooks to Git, I have a filter that scrubs the output by using `jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True --to=notebook --stdin --stdout`.

This works fine locally with git commits in VSCode in the source control view (⌃⇧G).

However when I connect to the same machine remotely via VSCode, I get errors that `jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True --to=notebook --stdin --stdout --log-level=ERROR: 1: jupyter: not found`.
Jupyter is in my `$PATH` and works locally. It also works when I use the terminal window in a remote VSCode session. It only fails in the remote source control view. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you defined your PATH: .profile or .bashrc.

- "[alter PATH for VS Code Remote SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55988854/6309)" mentions  I modified the path in ~/.bashrc and it worked.
- "[Set global $PATH environment variable in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70924092/6309)" suggests:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and then type Open Settings (JSON), and simply add the following line.
>
> ```
> "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": true
> ```

Comment: That line was already there in my settings

Comment: @pgcudahy OK. And would the first point help? (the one about `~/.bashrc` path)