# How to avoid conda activate base from automatically executing in my VS Code editor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, visual-studio-code

```
PS E:\Python and Data Science\PythonDatabase> conda activate base
conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling    
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ conda activate base
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (conda:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS E:\Python and Data Science\PythonDatabase> & C:/Users/Lenovo/Anaconda3/python.exe "e:/Python and Data Science/PythonDatabase/CourseHelper.py"
Hello World
PS E:\Python and Data Science\PythonDatabase>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can set `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false` in your settings to [deactivate activation of your environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment). Alternatively, you can set `"python.condaPath"` to [where `conda` exists](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_conda-environments) so the extension can use conda appropriately.

Comment: Thanks! "Set "python.condaPath" to where conda exists so the extension can use conda appropriately." - This worked for me.
To be more specific, go to vscode settings -> search "python.condaPath" -> you may see an empty box -> type conda path ( C:\Users\YourUserName\anaconda3\Scripts )

Answer (score 0):

Building on @[Brett Cannon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60981628/11262633)'s answer...

You have 2 options.  Unless otherwise noted, all of the following assume you are changing VSCode Settings (`F1` -> `Terminal:Configure Terminal Settings`).

**Option 1**

Use the Command Prompt instead of PowerShell.

1. Switch your VSCode terminal to the Command Prompt
   [image]
2. In the `settings.json` file, set the `"python.condaPath"` to your `conda.exe`.  E.g.

```
"python.condaPath": "C:\\Users\\<user id>\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\conda.exe"
```

**Option 2**

Set the `PATH` variable.

1. Add the path to conda.exe to your PATH environment variable (per https://stackoverflow.com/a/66259191/11262633):

```
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
            "PATH": "${env:PATH};C:\\Users\\<user id>\\Anaconda3\\Scripts"
    }
```

2. Start a PowerShell terminal.  You will get a message stating that Conda has not been initialized.  Run the following command:

```
conda init
```

Note that as of the writing of this answer, `conda init --help` states that this command is experimental.

MicroSoft [states](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-conda-environment) that VSCode doesn't currently support automatically activating Conda environments using PowerShell.  However, option 2 seems to work.