# VS Code integrated terminal on Mac OS not finding node.js

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, terminal

If I open a terminal window at a folder and type:
`node -v`
I get:
`v12.16.2`

If I do the same from my integrated terminal in the same folder in VS code:
`node -v`
I get:
`node: Command not found.`

This worked fine until recently (presumably a VS code update). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The comment response to the question on this page: [Set global $PATH environment variable in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983718/set-global-path-environment-variable-in-vs-code)

... told me that VS Code reads .tcshrc (or equivalent for other shells). So I added
`set path=($path /usr/local/bin)`
to .tcshrc and restarted VS code.

https://superuser.com/questions/224974/how-do-i-add-a-location-to-my-path-in-unix

Answer (score 0):

Add node to your path and then you can use it anywhere,
you can follow this https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/

Comment: Thanks Dani, but /usr/local/bin is already in the path (and that's where node is located). The problem lies with VS Code:
Terminal:
`echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:.... etc...`
VS Code:
`echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

How can I set the path in VS Code?

Comment: I've since read that VSCode will read from .tcshrc (or equivalent for other shells) so I added set path=($path /usr/local/bin) to .tchsrc and now working as it should. Thanks for your help.