# VsCode says Python directory is not on PATH (MacOS)

Tags: python, pip, path

`WARNING: The scripts pip, pip3 and pip3.8 are installed in "/Users/my_name/Library/Python/3.8/bin" which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.`

When I check `/etc/paths` I can see the above path in there

[image: /etc/paths contents]

When I try to use `pip` it says that it is not installed

Comment: Your shell (or your profile scripts) might not be using `/etc/paths` to construct the `PATH` environment variable. What does `echo $PATH` say?

Comment: Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356688/what-is-the-difference-between-echo-path-and-etc-paths/356720

Comment: @Selcuk `$PATH` in VsCode is:

/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin

    while `$PATH` in terminal is:

/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/ethanonweller/Library/Python/3.8/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin

Comment: Are you having issues running `pip` from within `VSCode`? You should fix the path issue for VSCode then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983718/set-global-path-environment-variable-in-vs-code

Comment: @Selcuk I should have clarified, yes, but that worked! thanks mate. I did not know there were multiple paths and assumed vscode was using /etc/path.