# How do I use manim with vs code and Anaconda?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, manim

**What I've done:**

- Installed Anaconda and ManimCE
- Selected the correct Python interpreter in VS Code (shows the expected version of Python)
- "added" (quotes since that's my problem) Anaconda into VS Code so that it says that it is the default terminal
- Written a Manim scene that doesn't have any errors

But then when I try to use the Anaconda terminal, the tab in the sidebar says it is Powershell and when I run the command "manim -pql file.py scene" to play the scene, manim isn't recognised.

Error message:

```
manim : The term 'manim' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file...
```

If I was using a library like numpy this wouldn't be a problem because I wouldn't have to use the terminal to access it but for manim I do.

Thanks for reading

Comment: You can add manim to your [Path variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983718/set-global-path-environment-variable-in-vs-code). Find its installation directory and append that to the list of paths in your vscode's settings.json.

Comment: Where have you installed the `ManimCE`? In the global python environment? Have you installed it in the anaconda environment?

Comment: Can you reply to comments? I dont know how to

I made an anaconda environment by following the instructions on the community documentation (cloning the git repo, creating the environment with python version 3.8 etc.)

I noticed something else: the powershell terminal in vs code says python is version 3.10.1 even though i've selected the 3.8.12 interpreter that is in the env i made

Comment: @Steven-MSFT
i worked out to mention people