# __FILE__ in perl returns paths without disk letter in visual studio code powershell

Tags: powershell, perl, visual-studio-code

I started today getting a problem with visual studio code and powershell running perl scripts.

After some debugging I found that I can not get the full path of the libraries anymore. For some reason powershell in visual studio code is returning the paths without the disk letter.

I made this script files to test it:

`test.pm`

```
package  Utils::test;
use strict;
use File::Basename;

use Exporter 'import'; 
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(test); 

sub test{
    print(__FILE__."\n");
}

1;
```

`test.pl`

```perl
use strict;
use File::Basename;
use Utils::test;

Utils::test->test()
```

In PowerShell:

[image]

In windows cmd:

[image]

In visual studio code power shell:

[image]

Both PS instances return the same versions:

```
Version
-------
5.1.19041.1320
```

I'm not sure if there was an update in Visual Studio Code since this started happening but it is right now in `1.65.0`.

I have no idea if this is an issue with powershell, perl or visual studio code.

*Update*: From the comments, it seems that there is a linux shell in my windows PS:
[image]

*Update2*: Thanks again to @ikegami it seems there are two different perls installed:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

`__FILE__` has always been the path used to open the file.

```
$ cat a.pl
CORE::say __FILE__;

$ perl a.pl
a.pl

$ perl ./a.pl
./a.pl

$ perl ././././a.pl
././././a.pl

$ perl ~/tmp/a/a.pl
/home/ikegami/tmp/a/a.pl
```

(Linux used here, but it's the same on Windows.)

If you want an absolute path, you can use

```perl
use Cwd qw( abs_path );

abs_path( __FILE__ )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I change to use abs_path, although in all scenarios the scripts where called from the same folder,but in visual studio I still get a "linux like" path. For example `/c/LocalWorkspace...` instead of `C:\LocalWorkspace...`

Comment: `Foo::Bar` gets translated to `Foo/Bar.pm`. Always been that way. Windows has always accepted both `/` and `\ ` as dir separators (and same goes for DOS before it), so that's fine.

Comment: But my problem comes from getting the absolute path `C:\ ` replaced by the unix `/c/` in visual studio. I have the perl5lib set with `setx PERL5LIB C:\LocalWorkspace\XXXXX\lib\` to store my libraries but for some reason the output in the powershell of visual studio differs from the powershell of my windows.

Comment: What? There's no `/c/` in the screenshots you posted. Do you mean `abs_path` is resulting in that? If so, you're not using Windows. Maybe you're using a unix emulation environment like Cygwin or MSYS? I think the latter mounts C: as `/c`. Of course `/` is used in unix.

Comment: I have a unix subsystem installed with debian, but It shuld not interfere with the powershell in visual studio, I have had that for months and never had this issue. And as you can see in the new screenshot I have added it should be everything windows powershell with normal windows paths. (I used your `abs_path` suggestion for `test.pl` in this scenario.)

Comment: Re "*It shuld not interfere with the powershell in visual studio*", Correct. It's not likely to be a `perl` from a WSL box. It's possible, but not likely.

Comment: Again, that could only happen in a unix system. Since your screenshot shows that you have a MSYS build of Perl installed on your system (as part of "Git Bash"), I'm going to bet that's the `perl` you're using to get that output.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot you are completly right, I have two different perls. I'm not sure how has that landed into de PS of visual studio. I have manually installed strawberry, But maybe as a dependency of some python library that got automatically installed?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the hints of @ikegami I have been able to track back what the issue was. There was another version of perl running in a MSYS which seems to be from git as `$Env:Path` showed.

So after checking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983718/set-global-path-environment-variable-in-vs-code) I saw that the property `Terminal Default Profile` was set to null, so I changed to powershell and it overtook the MS path and after a restart everything started to work again as expected.

[image]

An update on this. I found the reason why this happens. I was starting code from gitbash with `code .`. When you do this the path gets changed to:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
```