# use a `task` to export a workspace-specific environment variable: $PATH?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have several workspaces that have unique environments.

When I load a workspace, I would like to update the linux `$PATH` accordingly, however, I tried the following:

```
### workspace.code-workspace
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {},
    "tasks": [
        {
          "command": "export $PATH=${workspaceFolder}/bin:$PATH"
        }
      ]
}
```

Which fails according to:

```
me@pc:~/Containers/cuda_devcon/project$ ls -alvh ./bin/julia 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me 21 Jan 29 17:38 ./bin/julia -> julia-1.6.7/bin/julia
me@pc:~/Containers/cuda_devcon/project$ which julia
me@pc:~/Containers/cuda_devcon/project$ julia

Command 'julia' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install julia  # version 1.8.5, or
sudo apt  install julia  # version 1.4.1+dfsg-1

See 'snap info julia' for additional versions.
```

Comment: julia is installed at `julia-1.6.7/bin/julia` which already executes in the environment

Comment: that's the point of the question, how to export a concatenated path successfully when the workspace is loaded

Comment: julia is just an example of an executable.  im happy to change the name if its distracting to you

Comment: Ah, I see. The structure of the question misled me: I assumed the error listing was the *result* of your executing the task, not the situation that made you want to execute it.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that the task is even executing?

Comment: Conceivably, this Q and A might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983718/set-global-path-environment-variable-in-vs-code?rq=1