# Add MinGW directory to $PATH only for Visual Studio Code

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, mingw, settings

I would like to use Visual Studio Code to compile and debug projects (C++, Nim), but I don't want to add the tool paths to my global Windows `PATH` settings, to avoid conflicts with other applications. In particular, I don't want to add the MinGW path.

How can I setup Visual Studio Code to add a path for all the tools - not only the terminal?

**What I have tried**

I saw a few similar questions, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983718/set-global-path-environment-variable-in-vs-code) which is somewhat outdated but has a few recent comments. I changed my VCS user settings by adding this:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "PATH": "${env:PATH}c:\\dev\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin"
},
```

and sure enough, if I open a terminal and type `gcc`, it executes normally, or if I check `$env:PATH`, I can see that it is set as expected.

But when I do `Start debugging` or `Run without debugging` from the editor, it fails:

> Problems loading reference 'vscode://schemas/ignoredSettings': Unable to load schema from 'vscode://schemas/ignoredSettings': cannot open vscode://schemas/ignoredSettings. Detail: Unable to resolve text model content for resource vscode://schemas/ignoredSettings.

Note that it works fine if I add the MinGW bin path to my Windows `PATH` instead, but that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: create a batch file or powershell script file that modifies the PATH and start VSC, call this script/batch file from the terminal outside VSC

Comment: @rioV8 Yes, that was the plan B, but I'm hoping for a smoother solution, that I can use seamlessly when launching VSC from the menu, the console or other apps. If I don't find anything else, I'll create a small executable that does exactly what you suggest.