# Github Desktop using different Visual Studio Code version from Anaconda

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-code, anaconda, github-desktop

I have read over 20 posts of an error running the code in .py file, but I still cannot get it running. I got an error like

> import requests Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
> line 1, in  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

> No version is set for command pip Consider adding one of the following
> versions in your config file at  python 3.8.13

> pip install requests
> File "", line 1
> pip install requests
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I want the visual studio code to run the .py file, I was able to run `.ipynb` just fine. However, I tried running the visual studio code on Anaconda, and, surprisingly, the code runs fine. Now, how to do I change the version of the visual studio code when I open it on the Github desktop to be the same as the anaconda one? I tried changing the interpreter, and it does not seem to work. The only solution now is to run VSC in anaconda.

Update 1: After several posts and google searches later, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983718/set-global-path-environment-variable-in-vs-code) to work for me. In order for the change to kick in, I need to restart the VSC as well.

Update 2: I found out that pressing shift + enter to run the python code on mac will screw up the terminal in VSC. I need to kill that terminal and rerun using only run button on the top right of the UI.

Comment: Hi @mingJie, thank you for your message. I clicked the "ticked mark" already. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 1: After several posts and google searches later, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983718/set-global-path-environment-variable-in-vs-code) to work for me. In order for the change to kick in, I need to restart the VSC as well.

Update 2: I found out that pressing shift + enter to run the python code on mac will screw up the terminal in VSC. I need to kill that terminal and rerun using only run button on the top right of the UI.