# Source environment script to automatically build CMake project in VSCode with Yocto SDK

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, yocto

I have CMake based project, which was currently build for desktop Linux (to quickly develop UI with QT QML and test it on desktop), but the target platform is embedded Linux and now I'm trying to integrate Yocto SDK into the project.

If I source the environment script `. ./toolchain/SDK/4.2.3/environment-setup-cortexa72-poky-linux` from the command line, I can successfully configure and cross-compile the application.

Before that I used VS Code CMakeTools extension with defined `CMakePresets.json` to automatically configure the project and build it from VS Code tasks (no need to use the terminal)

The issue I'm having now is, how to integrate sourcing of `environment-setup-cortexa72-poky-linux` script into my work process. As this script also defines an alternative cmake executable.

It would be nice if I could define a task, which can be run at the beginning and source the script to have correct environment variables. So that later I can use CMake Configure task and Build task and etc.

Is there any way to do it?

I've tried searching for some way to do it from CMake Tools extension side, but could not find any

Comment: there are settings for CMake Tools to set environment variables for various procedures: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md#cmake-settings is that sufficient?

Comment: Well not really, as I would need to manually define all environment variables, for now I resorted to using `environmentSetupScript` and discarding my CMakePresets in favor of CMake-kits.json from CMake Tools. But I would prefer CMakePresets overall

Comment: Basically I used this answer for now - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76355581/22162587

Answer (score 1):

(This is a [partial answer](/help/how-to-answer) written to help understand the relevant limitations of CMake and the CMake Tools VS Code extension)

Since you mentioned [this answer post](/a/76355581/22162587) which suggests using `environmentSetupScript` in a CMake kit (which CMake Tools currently doesn't have a similar mechanism for when using presets instead of Kits), TL;DR, devs have been evaluating allowing specifying a `environmentSetupScript` in the vendor bits of a CMakePresets.json, and have various design reasons to not do that. You can read the full thoughts in the following:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/1885#issuecomment-848239346 (maintainer comment in "Support for microsoft.com/VisualStudioSettings/CMake/1.0 vendor option in CMakePresets.json #1885"- an issue ticket in the CMake Tools VS Code extension)
- [presets: sourcing environment scripts](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21619) a feature request in the CMake issue tracker.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Helped to understand the issue here!