Segmentation fault because of wrong path
I just installed MSYS2 following the VS Code setup guide, and I’m able to compile code with g++ successfully. However, when I try to run it, I keep encountering a segmentation fault error. Here’s what I’m seeing in the debugger log:
Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'D:\Programme\Python\Library\mingw-w64\bin\libstdc++-6.dll'. Symbols loaded.
...
Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x000000006fcae829 in ?? () from D:\Programme\Python\Library\mingw-w64\bin\libstdc++-6.dll

This is the code for testing:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<"Hello World";
    return 0;
}

It seems that the issue is with the libstdc++-6.dll file. The debugger is loading it from an unexpected Python directory (D:\Programme\Python\Library\mingw-w64\bin), where some version of MinGW appears to be installed (not sure why it's there, came with python I guess).
If I search for libstdc++-6.dll on my system, I find multiple copies, such as in Arduino and NordVPN directories. Ideally, VS Code should be picking up the correct version of this file, located in my MSYS2 installation.
If I delete the libstdc++-6.dll file from the Python directory, the segmentation fault issue goes away, and everything works fine. But I’m concerned that deleting it could break my Python installation or other dependencies in the future.
For context:

The path to C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin is the first entry in both my user and system PATH variables, so it should prioritize the MSYS2 version.

Does anyone know how I can prevent this error without manually deleting the .dll file from other directories?
I found a walkaround, when I create a launch.json file everything works:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Run C++",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
          {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
          }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\gdb.exe"
      }
    ]
  }

This fixes everything and I dont get errors anymore. Do I need this on every task? It should be possible to run without having to create this every time.
EDIT
Thanks for the help!
I tried all the suggested solutions, but none worked. After a hardware change on my computer, I reinstalled Windows, VS Code, MSYS2 and everything worked properly.
Unfortunately, I can't pinpoint the exact cause of the issue. Reinstalling is most likely not a good solution for others facing the same problem.
However, when I still had the issue, the launch.json file helped that i could compile and run the code. I recommend starting there to investigate how the .json file affects the dll's that are called when compiling. It might lead to a solution.

I suspect that D:\Programme\Python\Library\mingw-w64\bin\libstdc++-6.dll is incompatible with the version of MinGW you used to compile your code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell

You have encountered DLL Hell. Something, could be a setting in the environment variables and could be VS Code itself, has placed this python path into the the PATH being used to find DLLs. Pop up a command prompt and enter echo %PATH%. If you don't see this phantom path, the problem is more likely at the VS Code side of things than the environment variables side.

Does anyone know how I can prevent this error without manually deleting the .dll file from other directories? Edit your PATH environment variable to remove this python. You may want to do that anyways since msys2 provides python.

can you restart your PC ? environment variable updates don't affect running apps

@AhmedAEK I tried restarting, but it doesn't have any effect.

@drescherjm I don't have any python environment variables in my PATH, this is the confusing thing. I dont know where VSCode gets this from.

Possibly in settings.json: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983718/how-can-i-globally-set-the-path-environment-variable-in-vs-code

@drescherjm Unfortunately I couldn't test this anymore.
