# VisualStudio Code Tasks and Variables

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual studio 2010 had an option when creating external tools to define an initial directory like $(ItemDir) which would be based on the file currently in focus. I am trying to do something similar in visual studio code but I cannot find an equivalent environment variable to do the same thing. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just to formalize the info into an answer:

Here is a list of predefined variables that can be used in tasks: [Variables reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference)

and here is more info on using variables in tasks : [Variable substitution](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_variable-substitution)

And this is really interesting from the last link above:

> Similarly, you can reference your project's configuration settings by
> prefixing the name with ${config:.
>
> For example,
> ${config:python.pythonPath} returns the Python extension setting
> pythonPath.
>
> Below is an example of a custom task configuration which
> executes autopep8 on the current file using your project's selected
> Python executable:

```
{
        "label": "autopep8 current file",
        "type": "process",
        "command": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
        "args": [
            "-m",
            "autopep8",
            "-i",
            "${file}"
        ]
    }
```

From the first link we see that you can even incorporate commands (like those used in keybindings and the command palette) into your tasks:

**Settings and command variables**

> You can reference VS Code settings and
> commands using the following syntax:
>
> ${config:Name} - example: ${config:editor.fontSize}
> ${command:CommandID} - example: ${command:explorer.newFolder}

Finally, related but because some people might end up here searching for these, there are variables that can be used in **snippets** (but not tasks).  See [Snippet Variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables)